# InRequestScope ObjectContext for IHttpModule

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I am doing login using a cookie by adding an `IHttpModule`. The module takes a dependency on my `DbContext`, which is set to be `InRequestScope` in the Ninject configuration. However, it seems the HTTP module gets a different `DbContext` than the rest of the code for the request, even though I use `(MyContext)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(MyContext));` in the `SendAsync` implementation.

How can I get the same instance of my `DbContext` in HTTP modules, `DelegatingHandler`s and in the actual request?

Comment: Have you tried using constructor injection instead of resolving it on the dependency resolver?

Comment: Constructor injection won't work for `IHttpModule` and `DelegatingHandler`, because they are instantiated once per app, not once per request.

Answer (score 1):

You need the ninject web common extension and the webapi extension for ninject. In our code it looks like the following and works even with Ctor injection:

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon 
{
    private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

    public static void Start()
    {
        ConfigureLogger();

        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }


    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        RegisterServices(kernel);

        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<AuthenticationHttpModule>();

        return kernel;
    }

    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
}
```

and for example our custom module

```
public class AuthenticationHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    private readonly IAuthenticationVerifier authenticateVerify;

    public AuthenticationHttpModule(IAuthenticationVerifier authenticateVerify)
    {
        this.authenticateVerify = authenticateVerify;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.AuthenticateRequest += this.OnAuthenticateRequest;
        application.EndRequest += this.OnEndRequest;
    }

    private void OnAuthenticateRequest(object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var app = (HttpApplication)source;

        try
        {
            var user = this.authenticateVerify.DoAuthentication(app.Request);

            app.Context.User = user;
        }
        catch (InvalidCredentialException)
        {
            this.DenyAccess(app);
        }
    }

    private void OnEndRequest(object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        ...
    }

}
```